# Importar códigos para reutilização em Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

[image: Img 1]

[image: Img 2]

Eu fiz essa classe da imagem 1, e queria reaproveitar, importar a classe toda pra ficar no lugar marcado da imagem 2, pra não precisar mudar em todas as páginas sempre que eu quiser atualizar alguma coisa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certo, vamos lá. Primeiramente na Imagem 1, você criou uma `PartialView`, e o que é uma `PartialView`?

> A Partial View ou Visão Parcial traduzido para o português pobre, é uma View onde seu código é reutilizável em vários outros lugares.

Como utilizar uma Partial View?

```js
@Html.Partial("NomeDaSuaView", model)
```

Sendo o model no exemplo acima um parâmetro adicional.

Mais informações:
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Isso mesmo que eu tava procurando, obrigado!